# Ubuntu Touch SDK - qmake problem

Tags: 13.04, 64-bit, ubuntu-touch, qt5

I've recently tried installing the Ubuntu SDK but with no luck! 
I followed the [Developer Instructions](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/) , and when I launch the QtCreator Ubuntu SDK and create anew project I don't have any options for creating a new touch project.

Also worth noting that some options on the left are greyed out. I have done my research and followed other answers for this but had no luck. I also seen a bug for it on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qtcreator/+bug/1135336) and followed their steps.

In Terminal when I run: 
`which qmake`
 I get: 
`/usr/bin/qmake`

When I run:

`qmake -v`

I get:

`qmake: could not find a Qt installation of ''`

As detailed in the [Lauchpad bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qtcreator/+bug/1135336) I've deleted config files and tried adding it manually.

If anyone has any ideas or are also having this problem, please let me know.

Thanks in advanced.

Also worth noting: I have done the classic "**Have you tried turning it off and on again**"

Comment: do you have `qt5-default` installed?

Comment: Yes I ran `sudo apt-get install qt5-default' and it was already there. I have also done a complete purge of the Ubuntu SDK and started from fresh but still no luck :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to of fixed itself. I just ran a system update today and it seemed to of worked!

Can't really give a fix for this problem, but I'll have a look through the updates. Might have been a packaging issue?

Thanks devs for the great software! :)